# Why does my script fail when running from udev?

Tags: bash, systemd, udev

I am writing a bash script and am checking whether the application is running. If it is not running it should be started in a separate process (not a child process). If it is running, the window should be maximized. I kind of made it but the new process terminates shortly after being started, probably because the script process ends. When I don't run it in background via &, the app doesn't close, but then I can't run the script a second time to maxmize the app.

```
#!/bin/bash
if pgrep app
then
    echo app is running
    # Maximize the app
    wmctrl -x -r WMClassOfapp -b "add,maximized_vert,maximized_horz"
else
    echo app is not running
    /usr/bin/app 
fi
```

When I execute it in a terminal, it works fine. When I call it from the udev rule, the app terminates. Using nohup yields the same outcome. Here is the udev rule

```
ACTION=="add" \
, KERNEL=="hci0:3585" \
, SUBSYSTEM=="bluetooth" \
, ENV{DISPLAY}=":0" \
, ENV{HOME}="/home/user"
, RUN+="/home/user/runapp"
```

Comment: Can you post the `udev` rule you used to start the service?

Comment: Just added the rules file. I actually don't want to use systemd, because that seems a bit too hacky to me. A rule that calls a service that calls a script...

Comment: Does it run for just a little time when using the `systemd` approach? Note that the `oneshot` type should be used with `RemainAfterExit=true`, otherwise it will never reach the `active` state, but directly transition to `dead`. The problem with starting a script from `udev` is that `udev` is now part of `systemd` anyway, and running a script from a `udev` rule may block processing of further `udev` events. `systemd` on the other hand mercilessly kills all processes and sub-processes started by a service when that service has ended ...

Comment: No it doesn't run at all. I just tried ``RemainAfterExit=true`` but the same happens. So when udev is a part of systemd anyway, I should not need systemd. I just want to start this app and keep it running. Like I said, it works when I don't run it in background in the script, but it needs to start in a separate process. Else I can't call the script a second time and maximize the app.

Comment: Is the `runApp` in your `ExecStart` line a typo? In your `udev` rule it was `runapp`  in all-lowercase ...

Comment: It is actually not called app. I just named it that for this post. There is no typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround here at last. You need a second script that contains

```
#!/bin/bash
echo /pathto/runApp | at now
```

This script has to be called from the udev rule. For it to work `at` has to be installed and you have to enable `atd` by calling `sudo systemctl enable atd --now`. It is a little hacky, but at least it works.

I deleted the systemd approach so the post will be an easier guide.